# Class Method Swapping Keeping Old Class 'Self'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble correctly function swapping between instance methods (python3).

Let's say I have SomeClass:

```
class SomeClass:

    def pSelf(self):
        # Do stuff with self.variables
```

In my particular case **I have two implementations of this class, a correct version and a buggy version**

Now I'll instantiate two objects of the type SomeClass (marked C for correct, B for buggy):

```
objOne = SomeClassC()
objTwo = SomeClassB()
```

I want objTwo to have the correct implementation of pSelf:

```
objTwo.pSelf = objOne.pSelf
```

However, objOne's method of pSelf is bound to objOne, so:

```
objTwo.pSelf() # This will do stuff with objOne.self!
```

I have tried to import type and perform the following:

```
objTwo.pSelf = types.MethodType(objOne.pSelf, objTwo)
```

As far as I can tell, this correctly binds the pSelf function to objTwo,
however then I receive an incorrect argument error - presumably because objTwo.pSelf now receives **two self arguments**.

I'm at a loss on how to go about this, what is the correct way to swap functions between two (similar) classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the function for the method before making a method out of it and some object

```
objTwo.pSelf = types.MethodType(objOne.pSelf.__func__, objTwo)
```

I would like to remark that this is a sign of a bad design.

Comment: What in particular is bad design? The reason for this bottle neck is I need to run two class functions against each other to test, while keeping sub functions (used within the swap functions) constant. Thank you by the way!

Comment: Well, if it is for mocking that's fine, but normally it is better to implement instances with different behavior with the strategy pattern.